# Sinon sequelize stub - Modified object not returned with Promise.resolve()

Tags: javascript, promise, sinon

I am mocking a Sequelize find call, and then modifying the result before returning the object in a Promise.resolve();

Here's my simplified code;

test.js

```
test('can pass test', t => {

    let mock_instance = models.myModel.build({
        a_property: 5
    });

    let Stub = sandbox.stub(models.myModel, 'find', () => {
        return Promise.resolve(mock_instance);
    });


    models.myModel.functionCall(mock_instance.id).then(returned_object => {

        let expected = {
            a_property: 6
        };

        t.equal(returned_object.get({plain:true}), expected);

        // Expected { a_property: 6 }
        // Actual { a_property: 5 }
        Stub.restore();

        t.end();
    });
})
```

model.js // Class method

```
classFunction: (id) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return sequelize.models.myModel.find({
              where: {
                id: id
              }
            }).then(mymodel => {

              mymodel.a_property++;

              resolve(mymodel);
            }).catch(err => {
              reject(err);
            });
          });
```

Why is this happening? I assume it's something to do with Sinon intercepting the resolve thinking it's the result of the find() call, but I'm not certain and I don't know how to fix it.

Is this an anti-pattern? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, `mymodel.a_property++` won't change the value in the underlying `dataValues` object (you'd need to call `set` to do this). When you call `returned_object.get({plain:true})` later it rebuilds the object from the underlying values.

Also, your "classFunction" can be a lot simpler. It doesn't need to wrap its result in an extra Promise:

```
classFunction: (id) => {
    return sequelize.models.myModel.find({
        where: { id: id }
    }).then(mymodel => {
        mymodel.set('a_property', mymodel.a_property + 1);
        return mymodel;
    });
};
```